# PHP - Writing to Host file programmatically

Tags: php, subdomain, host, saas

I am doing my project implementation in **localhost Xampp** installation

Part of my project is ,

When the user sign up on my page he will be asked for his desired sub domain and from then on his URL will be :

> chosensubdomain.mysite.com

Everything works perfectly , except for sub domain i have to manually add the entries in windows host file as follows

```
127.0.0.1       chosensubdomain.mysite.com   abc.mysite.com  xyz.mysite.com
```

What i want was when the form submits the host file should be added up with a entry

I am not sure that whether it is possible to make entry in Windows Host file programmatically using PHP .

Kindly help me out with this mates ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is very possible, a better, time saving approach will be to use your programming language of choice to dynamically create sub-folders on the server then use a `.htaccess` file to rewrite `http://foo.com/bar` to `http://bar.foo.com`. [This](http://www.9lessons.info/2016/03/how-to-create-dynamic-subdomains-using-php-and-htaccess.html) should help you if you're on a live server or you use [Zpanel](http://www.zpanelcp.com/) on a local machine (For ease of advanced dns control) else you can manually add a catch-all (*) sub-domain in your host file.

```
*.foo.com       IN  A       127.0.0.1
```

If you still want to do it the ol' way, you have to use PHP's I/O functions to append text dynamically to your host file.

```
$sub_domain = "   foo.bar.com";
$append = file_put_contents('C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts', $sub_domain.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

I actually think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183928/how-to-let-php-to-create-subdomain-automatically-for-each-user?rq=1) answers your question better.

Comment: Thanks , the ol' way i preferred and that worked mate

Answer (score 1):

Keeping writing new entries to hosts is not a good way.

Here is my idea: Use `Dnsmasq` on your local environment.

For Example: Setup [Dnsmasq on OSX](https://passingcuriosity.com/2013/dnsmasq-dev-osx/)

The rule for dnsmasq should be set to resolve any domain ending with `mysite.com` to `127.0.0.1`

In such way, all your subdomain matched on your local environment will point to localhost, which get your problem solved.

In production environment, you may set a wildcard A or AAAA (maybe) record for your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice and for the solution mate. i''l try out